# Can't access office365 using oauth to get user info. Need endpoint and JWT parser

Tags: java, oauth, office365, jwt

I got access token, refresh token and id token using the authorisation code for MS Office 365 by the below endpoint.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

I don't have endpoints to fetch the user info and read the emails.

Where can I get these endpoints?
Can anyone post me the valid endpoints for the same.

Also,
How to use JWT to decode the access token, for the user details?
Is there any working JWT parser for parsing payload of the access token?